# Connection to Git daemon on Windows 7 getting "reset by peer" error

Tags: windows, git, git-daemon

I'm running the Git dameon on Win7 (Ultimate - x64) from MinGW. When I first start the daemon (as in first time it runs since the last restart), I can perform any command on the server from a remote computer without incident.

However, after a while, commands will fail with `fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer`. I've tried restarting the daemon, restarting my connection to the network, and disabling and enabling my wireless adapter. The only solution is a reboot.

I have verbosity turned on and the daemon sees the incoming connection. From the output, it seems like the server handles the command normally:

```
[7232] Connection from 192.168.2.169:60163
[7232] Extended attributes (19 bytes) exist <host=192.168.2.99>
[7232] Request upload-pack for '/asterisk-config-client'
[2964] [7232] Disconnected
```

Typically, I call any Git commands from a virtual machine on my computer. So, I attempted to run commands locally (I can use Git without MinGW, but I prefer not to) and still got the same error. I even tried to start the daemon outside of MinGW (without restarting my computer) with no luck.

From what I can tell, it sounds like the socket binding is getting messed up. But I have no idea how to clear a socket or anything like that on Windows. When it comes to administration, I like Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Windows firewall is known to cause this error. try disabling it and see if it improves.

Comment: The Windows firewall is off (according to the Security Center), but I just saw the service was still on. After I stopped the service, I setup a test repo to fetch from. It worked for a bit, but then gave the reset error. I kept attempting to fetch and after about 20 attempts, it worked once. So, I committed another change and attempted the fetch again. I got the reset error and I haven't been able to fetch since.

Comment: Btw, that was after a restart.